# javascript replace each occurrence of a character when they occur consecutively

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

so I want to replace each '+' in this string to a space ' '

`EST++++++++++%5E0+90310++162`

So the output I want is:

`EST          %5E0 90310  162`

I've tried this:

```
var l = l.replace(/\+/g, " ");
```

Which works alittle except when they occur consecutively, it replaces all the consecutive +'s with a single space.

So I'm getting this instead of what I want:
`EST %5E0 90310 162`

Comment: "it replaces all the consecutive +'s with a single space." - nope, it doesn't. It's because you're viewing the string in your browser it makes it look like there's only one space. Try the same in the console.

Comment: but I'm getting the correct result [see Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1cOf4z/1)

Comment: because the editor did not see the whitespace as whitespace

Comment: @Kinduser they have changed because in the original post, the problem this question is about *happened to the post itself*. She wrote multiple spaces in Markdown but it was displayed as one in HTML. And then, several people tried fixing it obviously with different understanding, which led to confusion and several changes of meaning from a bystander's perspective. In these situations it is really enlightening to check the edit log and the original Markdown used there.

Comment: Your code works fine on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dvLokmj/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic powers tell me that you are actually getting multiple spaces just fine, but you are displaying it as HTML and there (as explained [here](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/white-space-handling/)) consecutive whitespace is collapsed to one space.

**EDIT**: In fact, it appears that exactly this happened to your question itself when you posted it, and caused some confusion in this thread ;)

If you want to keep the whitespace, either replace it with a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;` in HTML - but this will modify the value of the string) or display it in a different way which preserves whitespace, for example inside a `<pre>` element of by using the CSS property `white-space: pre;` on the containing element.

See this example:

```js
var value = 'EST++++++++++%5E0+90310++162'.replace(/\+/g, " ");

document.getElementById('element1').innerHTML = value;
document.getElementById('element2').innerHTML = value;
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="element1"></span>
</p>
<p>
  <pre id="element2"></pre>
</p>
```

(Or, if you are assigning the content using `.innerHTML` like I did in my snippet, the solution could be as simple as changing to `.innerText`. But I don't know where you use this code exactly so it can be that this solution doesn't apply.)

Comment: Nice answer, very detailed!

Comment: Great answer! Thats exactly what it was, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me, maybe the way you are outputting the value is trimming extra spaces?

```js
var l = 'EST++++++++++%5E0+90310++162'

//'EST          %5E0 90310  162'

l = l.replace(/\+/g, " ");
console.log(l);
```

Comment: You were right !! I was outputing it in html which was trimming all the extra spaces.  I did instead a replace by a nonbreaking space which fixed the issue.  l = l.replace(/\+/g, '&nbsp;');

Comment: Always glad to help!